# Emacs Mode Line Click Change Buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer, mouse, modeline

In some installation of Emacs for the terminal, I had that if you click (text mouse cursor) on the buffer name in the mode line it jumped to the next buffer.

I search for a while but I couldn't find it.

Do someone remembers how to achieve this.

OS   : OS X Terminal
Emacs: GNU Emacs 26.3
(Now I have Catalina, but I should have been in previous versions)

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on mouse mode in your terminal emacs: `M-x xterm-mouse-mode RET`. This seems to work with `emacs -nw` in either an `xterm` or a `gnome-terminal` on linux. Whether it works on OS X and whatever terminal emulator it provides, I have no idea.

This [Unix & Linux SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252995/how-can-mouse-support-be-enabled-in-terminal-emacs) contains much more information and some useful links.